# What is the standard place to store a SQLite database for an Android project?

Tags: android, sqlite, firefox-addon

When creating a SQLite database (I'm using the SQLite Manager Firefox plugin), I naturally first want to create a new database. Is there a "preferred" folder to use in which to save the database? Should it be the android project's main directory, a subdirectory thereof, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to have the database packaged in the apk then it has to go in one of the resource directories so you can then copy it out to a working directory on the device when the app is first run.

Either the project's `/res/assets` directory or the `/res/raw` directory.